# No puedo restringir tamaño de los vídeos de Vimeo que añado en Divi (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Tengo una web en Wordpress con el Divi Builder. Cuando inserto o añado un módulo de vídeo con una URL de un vídeo de Vimeo o un módulo de código con el código de inserción (tengo mi cuenta y suscripción PLUS a Vimeo), resulta que el vídeo (normalmente formato 16:9) toma un espacio contenedor (iframe) cuadrado, lo cual me rompe el diseño.

Es decir, si yo le preparo un contenedor rectangular (16:9) para que queda el vídeo ajustado a ese contenedor, resulta que el vídeo; el contenedor (normalmente una columna de una fila de Divi) se convierte en un cuadrado 1:1. El vídeo sigue su relación 16:9, pero el espacio que toma se duplica (1:1). Por lo que queda mal. He probado a restringir las medidas del contenedor de varias maneras, pero el Video se reproduce mal en la web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se aprecia que es una fila (rectángulo verde), con dos columnas iguales y cada vídeo en un módulo de código (video insertado). En teoria, las columnas (contenedores) de los vídeos deberían de ser rectangulares y estar ajustados por que yo restrinjo el tamaño y forma de los módulos de código con los vídeos. Pero se observa que hay un espacio en "blanco" tomado por cada vídeo que incluso se sobresale y no se ve en la captura.Las medidas del vídeo las pone Vimeo con su código, también lo he modificado y eso no influye en su iframe.

Espero que haya quedado claro lo que trato de explicar. La pregunta ¿como puedo restringir esa caja iframe que Vimeo consigue fijar?

Gracias